# Update View based on Model automatically

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

So I've been playing with the MVC website in VS 2013. I'm new to the concept of MVC and am trying to wrap my head around it. I have been following [this turtorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/security/using-oauth-providers-with-mvc)

What I am trying to understand specifically here is - Is it possible to have the view update itself dynamically based upon Attributes assigned to properties in the model. Take the following for example:

```
  public class ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Full Name")]
    public string Fullname { get; set; }

}
```

No in this class we have 2 properties UserName and Fullname. Both are marked with required and they have display attributes set.

And here is the view.

`<li>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FullName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FullName)
</li>
<li>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
</li>`

So is it possible to use the attributes on the model properties to auto-magically create the view so I dont have to update 3 locations everytime I change the model?

Thanks for the thoughts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, ASP.NET MVC doesn't do this. It's meant for applications where you want views that are highly customized.

The term you're looking for is [Scaffolding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scaffold_%28programming%29). There's a not-very-well-supported project called [MvcScaffolding](http://mvcscaffolding.codeplex.com/), but the real deal for scaffolding in .NET is [ASP.NET Dynamic Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee845452.ASPX), which I suggest you have a look at if you just need to throw together a really quick CRUD UI and don't care all that much how it looks.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the public interface of your model, you will have to correct the code everywhere where it is used. So if you decide to rename the public property `FullName` to `CompleteName` You'll have update your code or it will not compile. If the code is embedded in a view, it will build but crash at runtime.